# Аналог JAXB/Gson для URL encoded строк

Tags: java

Допустим есть простой POJO:

```
public class CustomRequest {
    private String param1;
    private String param2;

    public CustomRequest() {
    }

    //getters and setters here
}
```

Сериализовать его в XML, JSON проблем нет.
Как его можно сериализовать в URL encoded строку?

Т.е. чтобы на выходе было:

```
param1=value1&param2=value2
```

Интересуют существующие решения/фреймворки типа JAXB, Gson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать аннотацию `@JsonAnySetter`(com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter) и класс `ObjectMapper`(com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper)

Пример кода:

```
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CustomRequest cr = new CustomRequest();
        cr.setParam1("hello");
        cr.setParam2("Привет");
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        System.out.println(mapper.convertValue(cr, MyURLFormatter.class));
    }
}

/**
 * Класс для преобразования
 *
 * @author Chubatiy
 */
class MyURLFormatter {

    public MyURLFormatter() {
    }
    //билдер для формирования строки
    private StringBuilder ulrBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    /**
     * Метод для добавления в uri
     */
    @JsonAnySetter
    public void add(String name, Object property) {
        if (ulrBuilder.length() > 0) {
            ulrBuilder.append("&");
        }
        ulrBuilder.append(name).append("=").append(property);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return ulrBuilder.toString();
    }
}

/**
 * Ваш класс
 *
 * @author Chubatiy
 */
class CustomRequest {

    private String param1;
    private String param2;

    public CustomRequest() {
    }

    public String getParam1() {
        return param1;
    }

    public void setParam1(String param1) {
        this.param1 = param1;
    }

    public String getParam2() {
        return param2;
    }

    public void setParam2(String param2) {
        this.param2 = param2;
    }

}
```

Результат:

```
param1=hello&param2=Привет
```

Comment: Работает спасибо. Обратно из param1=hello&param2=Привет в CustomRequest возможно?

Comment: К сожалению не подскажу. Единственное что приходит на ум, так это преобразовать полученную строку в полноценный объект json(т.е. `param1=hello&param2=Привет` в `{"param1":"hello","param2":"Привет"}`) и потом тем же методом (`mapper.convertValue(json, CustomRequest.class)`) в класс

Comment: Спасибо еще раз. Видимо придется запилить что-то своё с блекджэком и аннотациями )